# Not able to login using admin prefix and changing controller name in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I added a prefix admin and changed the controller from **Userscontroller** to **LoginController** now the **localhost:8765/admin** works fine but **localhost:8765/admin/login/check_login** sbut when i submit my form it give me a error **Error: The requested address '/admin/login/check-login' was not found on this server** where **check_login is my auth action**

**Router**

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'display','login']);
});
```

**App Controller**

```
   public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Login',
            'action' => 'check_login',
            'prefix' => 'admin'
        ],
    ]);

    // Allow the display action so our pages controller
    // continues to work.
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
```

**Check Login Action**

```
public function check_login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $admin = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($admin) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($admin);
            $result['status'] = 'success';
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $result['status'] = 'failure';
        $result['message'] = 'Your username or password is incorrect';
        echo json_encode($result);
        die;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the custom port number included in the URL when you get the error message?

Comment: Yes, now it is working but now in, login action when $this->Auth->identify() is read it gives an internal server error

Comment: I changed the action check_login to login

Answer (score 1):

Why are you complicating? The easiest way:

1. Create `Admin` folder in you Controller app folder.
2. Inside - create UsersController.php and make login method. All functions inside `Admin` folder will be using only with `Admin` prefix in URL.

Next - You can map the URL /admin/login to your login() action of users controller using following route:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // Because you are in the admin scope,
    // you do not need to include the /admin prefix
    // or the admin route element.
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
});
```

This is the easiest way.